# Selecting feature (point) based on specific attribute value(s) of another layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

How do i select a feature (point) based on a specific attribute value(s) of another layer?

Scenario:

One layer (map) polygons representing disease risk across a continent, with several columns representing different attributes (risk scale 1-4 etc.) and another layer with point features representing individual movement over time.

I would like to select point features which are overlayed on polygons with a risk scale above 2.5.

Comment: Select By Location * 2 --explain further

Answer (score 1):

As @BERA suggests in the comments, you want to do a two part selection using [Select by Attribute](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-attributes.htm) and [Select by Location](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm). First, use Select by Attribute to select the polygons with a risk scale above 2.5 Then second, use Select by Location to select the points that are within these polygons ("intersect the source layer feature" will be a fine spatial selection for your needs). Your target layer will be the points, and your source layer will be the polygons. Make sure to check the "use selected features" box.